# Common Pre-Complilation Header for iOS and OS X Targets

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode6, uikit

I have a project that shares code between iOS and OS X targets. iOS target compiles fine. But OS X target somehow includes one particular Static library class that imports UIKit framework and for obvious reasons throws an error. I do not need to include that category in OS X target. I have deselected OS X target from that file's target membership tab in file inspector. Being new to OS X development I don't know where to look to not include that class while compiling for OSX. What possibly I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The header should look something like:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
// iOS code
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

In `XCode`:

> 1. Select the Target you wish to exclude the class or library from
> 2. Click on `Build Phases` > `Compile Sources` or `Link Binary With Libraries`
> 3. Select the class or library to exclude and hit `-`

The class should no longer get compiled with that target.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see that class file in Build Phases > Compile Sources.

Comment: Part of a static library.

Comment: How are you linking the static library? It appears the library itself might be the issue here.

Comment: I have linked the static libraries for iOS targets by adding them to Build Phases > Link binary with Libraries. But for OS X target those are not linked. My understanding is that it shouldn't include those files then. Correct?

Comment: Correct. You might need to go to `Product` > `Manage Schemes` and recreate the one for the `OS X` target. If the static library is something that can be used for `OS X` and `iOS` and you are compiling it from source then you should be able to include `ifdef` statements to avoid the `UIKit` imports on `OS X`. It's unclear though if you are using the static library with `OS X`.

Comment: I am not using that library with OS X. You mean I should create not Target for OS X all over again?this is what my pch looks like. http://pastebin.com/vk7DFvbS

Comment: You must have a linker flag an import statement somewhere within your `OS X` code that is including it, since there really aren't any other things in `XCode` that would link the library. What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: I looked at your paste - The `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` should be in the iphone section, `#ifdef __OBJC__` applies to both `iOS` and `OSX` and includes it in both.

Comment: ah good to know that. however that still doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77667/discussion-between-zhr-and-lll).